# How to draw sequence of shapes with arrows and text

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, shapes

I'm trying to draw something of the sort 
[image]

with a square figure in the far left, and a rectangular figure cut into 4 slices on the right-hand side. Above the arrows and below the figures reads "text". The middle portion consists of `$\Omega_i$`'s, with arrows coming from `$\Omega_1$`, `$\Omega_j$`, and `$\Omega_k$`.

How would one draw such a figure?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,matrix,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1cm and 1.5cm,
arrow/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex,
  shorten >= 3pt,
  shorten <= 3pt,
}
]
\node[draw,minimum size=3cm,label={270:text}]
  (rect) {};
\coordinate[right=of rect] (aux);
\matrix[matrix of math nodes]
  at ([xshift=8pt]aux)
  (mat)
  {
    \Omega_i \\
    \vdots \\
    \Omega_j \\
    \vdots \\
    \Omega_k \\
  };
\node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal=true,right=1.5cm of mat,minimum size=1cm,label={270:text}] 
  (rectiv) {};
\node[circle,draw,right=of rectiv,minimum size=1cm,label={270:text}]
  (circ)  {};
\draw[arrow]
  (rect) -- node[above] {text} (aux);        
\foreach \Valor/\Texto/\Pos in {1/texti/above,3/textj/above,5/textk/below}
{
\draw[arrow]
  (mat-\Valor-1.east) -- node[pos=0.3,\Pos,sloped] {\Texto} (rectiv.west);        
}
\draw[arrow]
  (rectiv) -- node[above] {text} (circ);        
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another version using nodes and arrows.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.multipart,positioning}

\tikzset{   
    split/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=4,
        rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split empty part width=4mm},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, -{Straight Barb}]

\node[draw, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=3cm, label=270:text] (big) at (0,0) {};
\node[right =of big] (oj) {$\Omega_j$};
\node[below =1.5cm of oj] (ok) {$\Omega_k$};
\node[above =1.5cm of oj] (oi) {$\Omega_i$};
\node[draw, split, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm, label=270:text, right =of oj] (multi) {};
\node[draw, circle, minimum size=4cm, right =of multi,label=270:text] (circ) {};

% lines and arrows
\draw (big) -- (oj) node[above, midway] {text};
\draw[-, thick, loosely dotted] (ok) -- (oj) -- (oi);
\draw (oj) -- (multi.west) node[above, midway] {text};
\draw (oi) -- (multi.160) node[above, midway, sloped] {text};
\draw (ok) -- (multi.200) node[above, midway, sloped] {text};
\draw (multi) -- (circ);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add separate text areas above the other two arrows on the omega nodes?

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Sure. See update.

Answer (score 4):

The `chains` library offers another possibility, especially convenient when used in conjunction with the `quotes` and `scopes` libraries. Nodes on chains are automatically named using the name of the chain and the count of nodes on that chain. Here, I call the chain `c1` so the nodes are `c1`, `c2` etc.

I also use two branches, `c2` and `c3`. The nodes on branches are named `<chain name>/<branch name>-<count of nodes on branch>` e.g. `c1/c2-2` means the second node on branch `c2` of chain `c1`.

A few styles are offered for convenience, and to ensure consistency in the placement and style of nodes, labels and edges.

Most edges are drawn using the `join` option from the `chains` library. The exceptions are the two diagonal arrows which it seemed easier to draw by hand.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows.meta,scopes,shapes.multipart,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    start chain=c1 going right,
    every on chain/.style={join},
    every edge/.append style={font=\scriptsize, shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
    >={Stealth[]},
    my join/.style={join=by {"#1"}},
    every edge quotes/.append style={midway, sloped, anchor=south},
    node distance=1 and 2,
  ]
  {[every join/.append style={->}]
    \node [on chain=c1, label=-90:text, text height=40pt, text width=40pt, draw] {};
    \node [on chain, my join=text] {$\Omega_j$};
    { [start branch=c2 going above ] }% manual 54
    { [start branch=c3 going below ] }
    \node [on chain, label=-90:text, draw, minimum height=20pt, rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=4, rectangle split ignore empty parts=false, my join=textj] {};
    \node [on chain, label=-90:text, draw, circle, minimum size=20pt, my join=text] {};
  }
  {[every join/.append style={densely dotted}]
    {[continue branch=c2]
      \node [on chain] {$\Omega_i$};
    }
    {[continue branch=c3]
      \node [on chain] {$\Omega_k$};
    }
  }
  \draw (c1/c2-2) edge [->, "texti"] (c1-3.west);
  \draw (c1/c3-2) edge [->, "textk"] (c1-3.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chained nodes]